# Spark 2.1 on Dataproc Image

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to spin up a Dataproc cluster using Spark 2.1.  Is there an image version that has Spark 2.1?  I see Spark 2.0 and 2.2, but not 2.1.

https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no dataproc image with Spark 2.1. Dataproc image 1.1 has Spark 2.0.2 and image 1.2 has Spark 2.2.3. Notice both are deprecated.